# Incorrect accent rendering on latex

Tags: pdftex, accents

The following text will render correctly into a PDF:

```
\'arbol -> árbol
Universit\"at -> Universität
Valpara\'iso -> Valparaíso
```

However, when I copy and paste from the PDF to another tool, I get the accents non on top of the character but the following:

```
\'arbol -> (C-c C-v) ->  ́arbol
Universit\"at -> (C-c C-v) -> Universit ̈at
Valpara\'iso -> (C-c C-v) -> Valpara ́ıso
```

Is it possible to correct this? I am using a [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/faangpath-simple-template/npsfpdqnxmbc) for typesetting my CV, but I realized that the CV is then parsed by recruiting bots with mistakes. I would like to fix this.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, you made my day! Actually, I must have learned this 20 years ago, then stopped using Latex and come back to step on the same problem.

Comment: @JorgeLópez if you're returning to LaTeX after 20 years, you should also realize that there's no need to be using accents like this in your source, just type the accented letters directly.

Comment: @AlanMunn, thanks for the reminder!. In fact, I used Latex a lot in the past, but I hard stopped about 5 years ago after a shift in my career. I knew all this stuff and had googled a lot more, using `fontenc` and `inputenc` was standard on my old Latex sources.